problems with uefibootmgr
i have make anything wrong with efibootmgr at my computer.
the system does not boot anymore. and in bios/uefi i do not see any nvme drive for booting.
the system has two nvme drives
nvme0n1 : skhynx 256gb and nvme1n1 : wd 1tb
nvme0n1 was the last from where i can until recently start my linux system.
grub tells me every time something with "booting into blind mode" or so, but the system does boot before i make anything wrong.
i tried to add nvme1n1 with efibootmgr to boot from.
now there is not any drive to boot from in bios/uefi.
i have now boot the system with a kubuntu usb key and then connected with ssh from an other computer to the system.
gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 | grep -A4 '^Partition table scan:'
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

gdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1 | grep -A4 '^Partition table scan:'
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

dmesg |grep efi
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.7 by American Megatrends

lsblk -f | grep nvme
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1        vfat        FAT12
├─nvme0n1p2        vfat        FAT32
├─nvme0n1p3        crypto_LUKS 2
│ └─nvme0n1p3crypt btrfs
├─nvme0n1p4        crypto_LUKS 2
│ └─nvme0n1p4crypt btrfs
└─nvme0n1p5        crypto_LUKS 2
  └─nvme0n1p5crypt ext4        1.0
nvme1n1
├─nvme1n1p1        vfat        FAT32
├─nvme1n1p2        crypto_LUKS 2
│ └─nvme1n1p2crypt btrfs
├─nvme1n1p3        crypto_LUKS 2
│ └─nvme1n1p3crypt btrfs
└─nvme1n1p4        ext4        1.0

the days before, i allways boot from nvme0n1, i will change to nvme1n1 now.
i will have the efi-parts and grub both together at nvme1n1p1.
i have now clear with efibootmgr all.
i have try this:
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -L "gentoo_grub_at_sk_hynix_256gb" -l "\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi"
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme1n1 -p 1 -L "gentoo_grub_at_wd_1tb"         -l "\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi"

efibootmgr shows me now:
Boot0000* gentoo_grub_at_sk_hynix_256gb HD(1,GPT,7127e659-ff38-43dc-938d-65e861d465ef,0x800,0x1000)/File(\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi)
Boot0001* gentoo_grub_at_wd_1tb HD(1,GPT,d11b9b38-0fb9-2241-994d-6051c2280651,0x800,0x200000)/File(\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi)
Boot0002* UEFI: SMI USB DISK 1100       PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(6,0)0000424f

than i do a reboot, but the system boot only from the kubuntu usb key.
i have seen something strange, if i now use efibootmgr i see:
Boot0000* gentoo_grub_at_sk_hynix_256gb VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0001* gentoo_grub_at_wd_1tb VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0002* UEFI: SMI USB DISK 1100       PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(6,0)0000424f

dont know what 99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb is, but why does both entries are the same and why now?
what have i to do that my system can boot from nvme1n1the \EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi-file ?
edit:
i have now try

efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -L "gentoo_grub_at_sk_hynix_256gb"
-l "\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi" -e 3 efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme1n1 -p 1 -L "gentoo_grub_at_wd_1tb"         -l "\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi" -e 3

the output from efibootmgr after reboot is
Boot0000* gentoo_grub_at_sk_hynix_256gb PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1b,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,AC-E4-2E-81-70-26-2B-18)/HD(1,GPT,7127e659-ff38-43dc-938d-65e861d465ef,0x800,0x1000)/File(\efi\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi)
Boot0001  gentoo_grub_at_wd_1tb PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-1B-44-8B-4A-88-8F-49)/HD(1,GPT,d11b9b38-0fb9-2241-994d-6051c2280651,0x800,0x200000)/File(\EFI\gentoo\grubx86.efi)

in bios/uefi i see now both drives nvme0n1 and nvme1n1, but i can not boot from.
edit2:
lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid
NAME        FSTYPE        SIZE FSUSED LABEL PARTLABEL        MOUNTPOINT     UUID                                 PARTUUID
sda                       3,6T                                                                                   
└─sda1      crypto_LUKS   3,6T                                              045113cb-b00f-4551-9b2c-67fb8d97499f df3d5eb6-bd5b-49e4-83bb-6a606e5be324
sdb                       3,6T                                                                                   
└─sdb1      crypto_LUKS   3,6T                                              189c8e42-f9c1-400a-91df-470124af0c19 6c138f9e-1802-45c0-ac72-4dc9015895b1
sdc                       7,3T                                                                                   
└─sdc1      crypto_LUKS   7,3T              Linux filesystem                26bca951-5441-471b-836c-295c38464710 a415550a-4cb8-424b-96cc-9229780f35d2
sdd                       7,3T                                                                                   
└─sdd1      crypto_LUKS   7,3T              Linux filesystem                3fb9ec1c-e5bb-4e94-b8be-14c31685f819 8609a2eb-f713-4eb4-b2f5-42e25875cd4d
sde                       7,3T                                                                                   
└─sde1      crypto_LUKS   7,3T              Linux filesystem                6576b74d-ffca-440e-bd92-857708f1d1fc 75e788df-10a5-4d20-b20a-0991f11e4310
sdf                       7,3T                                                                                   
└─sdf1      crypto_LUKS   7,3T              Linux filesystem                9abfd98b-c315-487d-8928-9e20c088be08 f2e36ad3-9403-4891-a9de-e0745058dd06
sdg         vfat         29,5G   3,9G                        /cdrom         A28D-C9E1                            
nvme0n1                 238,5G                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat            2M   136K       EFI System       /mnt/nvme0n1p1 20F5-4103                            7127e659-ff38-43dc-938d-65e861d465ef
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat            1G              Linux filesystem                2142-7173                            07365df9-524f-466c-9a3b-21d6f33fa6ba
├─nvme0n1p3 crypto_LUKS    32G              Linux filesystem                3a920ea9-b868-46f0-9101-c926c4b894d5 f7f48cdc-7fed-404c-9c0a-dfd36b482998
├─nvme0n1p4 crypto_LUKS    32G              Linux filesystem                fdb55604-1ca8-4aa3-8af7-41697d63fc32 a5f3d5b8-23d7-428c-a27b-1cf3f83267f3
└─nvme0n1p5 crypto_LUKS 173,5G              Linux filesystem                c5747f0e-8f2d-4df8-82e2-46715d854d0d 750219f3-218c-4b96-b467-8f5d8c2f41de
nvme1n1                 931,5G                                                                                   
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat            1G  30,2M                        /mnt/nvme1n1p1 48B1-0A01                            d11b9b38-0fb9-2241-994d-6051c2280651
├─nvme1n1p2 crypto_LUKS    64G                                              41371f53-e543-4930-a249-ef897cdd0061 f7ee6083-3818-448b-8b35-0007db43068b
├─nvme1n1p3 crypto_LUKS    64G                                              6ff6fad4-3bf0-4f30-a67c-748163638949 37241146-de30-4fa2-9f93-1e7c48c20a21
└─nvme1n1p4 ext4        802,5G                                              49551619-c398-48a4-a991-507c552cbc83 1129fbc5-f848-43c6-a9fa-c0fdd75690b7

here is the output from boot-repair.
pastebin-link -> https://pastebin.com/CV0ffCNd
i have tried to add both lines again with -e 1 instead -e 3, they are than again with VenHw.
so i deleted them again and add them new with again -e 3.
it is a gigabyte branded motherboard.
secure boot is disabled.
i do absolute not understand why they are now listed both in uefi/bios but can not boot them!?
edit3:
i remember in the uefi/bios is the usb key with the kubuntu live system named with "UEFI....." the both nvme drives are not named with "UEFI" ... only with "gentoo_grub_...." , does that mean something?
edit4:
on an othere machine (pc2) they can boot and works, i see in efibootmgr
efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* gentoo        HD(1,GPT,84f1773e-3b98-433a-8925-3e292f99183b,0x800,0x1000)/\EFI\gentoo\grubx64.efi

i remember before i try anything at pc1, they at the moment does not can boot, the line looks similar to the from pc2.
at pc1 in efibootmgr, there was nothing with pciroot, nothing with VenHw and nothing with like 00-1B-44-8B-.. . what does i make wrong with efibootmgr? i can remember that i have set at pc1 and or pc2 anything with efibootmgr. are there other programm for that?

UEFI uses GUID/partuuid to find ESP. You can see partuuid with: lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose an install & chose which drive to put boot files into. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Understanding UEFI boot process

Do you happen to have a MSI branded motherboard and MSI branded UEFI firmware?

Do you have secure boot enabled in the firmware (BIOS) setup? If so, could you try with secure boot disabled to see if it makes any difference?

have make some edits in my first post - is that a uefi/bios problem that i can not boot from? which way should i use if i want to install grub new?
